# Does WSL2 docker need windows docker desktop?

Tags: wsl2

I tried to search some web page and found they teach you have to install windows docker desktop.
I confuse about it , because MS said WSL2 is based on `Linux Core` so it should not need windows desktop theoretically.

[Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/) said it need docker desktop but i can install and build docker in WSL2 with this script and there's no windows docker desktop.

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
$ sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker Desktop provides out-of-the-box integration with Windows like the `docker` CLI and folder mappings.

You do not need Docker Desktop if you don’t want these. You’re not looking at the Docker engine documentation but at the Docker Desktop documentation. WSL 2 is just Linux, so you can install any Linux software (that doesn’t have special hardware or exotic kernel feature requirements).

You can also set up the `docker` CLI manually, if desired, using `DOCKER_HOST`… environment variables.